# PHP redirect not working - php headers

Tags: php, redirect

When I load my index.php file, the header.php,sidebar.php, or nav.php don't show up. I used "include" correctly, and in the validators there is no error. All of the files work by themselves. Here is the code.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Homepage</title>

<style>
@import url(stylesheet.css)

</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id ="header">
<?php include('header.php');?>
</div>

<div id="navigation">
<?php 
include('nav.php');
?>
</div>

<div class = "homepagemain" id="homepagemain">
<h2><strong><em>What is ZapDebate?</em></strong></h2>
<p>Zap Debate is a website where you can debate on a hot topic. Just find the topic you      want and fight! The debates will be out for 14 days at a time, and whoever gets the most      likes wins the debate!ZapDebate is a place to practice debating, or just share your  opinion. So go on! Fight!</p>
</div>

<div id = "sidebar">
<?php include('sidebar.php');?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<h1 class="header"><strong><em>Zap Debate</em></strong></h1>

</html>
```

nav.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Debates</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Recent News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hot Topics</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Suggest a Debate!</a></li>
</ul>

</html>
```

sidebar.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<h2 class="sidebar">Popular Searches</h2>

</html>
```

Comment: make sure the path is correct.

Comment: How is this related to redirect and php headers?

Comment: i do not understand what you mean by path. sorry i am very new to php.

Comment: You should not be repeating the doctype and `<html>` wrapper in your header and sidebar. You can just include those as HTML fragments.

Comment: he says you should make sure all the files are in the same folder

Comment: Tried `error_reporting`? Looked at the HTML source ouput? PHP actually enabled on your server etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you actually have an apache server started, with php enabled.

The next step would be to make sure the relative path to the other files is correct. What does this mean? It means that :

```
<?php include('sidebar.php');?>
```

this code assumes sidebar.php and the page you accessed, in this case index.php are on the same folder. If they are not, you should make the relative path till there. For example if index.php is in the /root folder and sidebar.php is in /root/tempFolder/ you should:

```
<?php include('tempFolder/sidebar.php');?>
```

Also, after that, when the other files were successfully loaded and you can see them, you should strip all the html in the files you include, as jeroen has suggested.

Edit: assuming you don't have an apache server started.

Asuming you're on windows, install a local server like wamp, easyphp or xampp, start it, copy the content in the local root folder(www, localweb or htdocs, if i remember correctly) and then you should enter go live with the following url: localhost.

For a xampp tutorial please follow : [this one](https://www.udemy.com/blog/xampp-tutorial/)

Comment: they are both in the same folder

Comment: you can run both of them, right?

try using require instead of include, but there shouldn't be any difference
check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: do you absolutely positively have to have apache running?

Comment: you have to have a server with apache running. asuming you're on windows, install a local server like wamp, easyphp or xampp, start it, copy the content in the local root folder(www, localweb or htdocs, if i remember correctly) and then you should enter on the url: http://localhost.

i hope you'll be fine from there

Comment: sorry about so much confusion. I am very, VERY new to php , html, and css.

Comment: try following the tutorial on easyphp here: http://www.easyphp.org/introduction.php

good luck.

Comment: so i downloaded xampp and started up apache. now what?

Comment: i updated the above post with a xampp tutorial, begin with Testing Your XAMPP Installation chapter.

Comment: radu vlad thanks so much! it finally works!

Comment: you could set my answer as a respose to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what the problem is exactly, but what you are doing is wrong: You are including complete html documents in your `#header`, `#navigation`, etc. elements.

To start, you should strip all the `html`, `head`, etc. tags from your includes.

For example your sidebar should just be:

```
<h2 class="sidebar">Popular Searches</h2>
```

You should also add a `body` tag to your main document and use an html validator on the result.

Comment: then how do i put the import the stylesheet in each one?

Comment: You don't need to. PHP ultimately assembles this into _one html document_. It has one doctype declaration, one `<html><head><body>`

Comment: @Eman936 It's already there, just look at the source of the html that comes back from the server.

Comment: ok i did what you said jeroen, but it still won't work.the problem is that when i load index.php, all that shows is "homepagemain" and nothing else